# about hadoop fs test command output

Tags: hadoop

I am running below command, tried to use either filename exists, or filename not exists, but none of them have any outputs from console. I expect if a file exists, the command should return zero?

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#test

```
hadoop fs -test -e filename
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it means the *return code* of the command is `0`.

You can check with

```
hadoop fs -test -e filename
echo $?
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
hadoop fs -test -d <HDFSFilename>
```

You should see 
    test: File does not exists

If the file does not exists - and a blank string if it does

```
1=$(hadoop fs test -d <HDFSFilename>)
```

I am sure you are using a HDFS filename and not a Linux based filename - but best check

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

Comment: The `-d` flag is for a directory, not a file. `-e` simply checks if the path exists, regardless of file or directory